# Best way to copy data from Elastic Search cluster to DDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

I am looking for a way to copy data from ES cluster to DDB. Any pointers would be helpful. Unfortunately there exists no resources online which I found useful.

Comment: Please ask for suggestions on reddit

Answer (score 0):

You and achieve this in 2 step:

1. Copy ES data to S3. you can use **elasticdump**. I found this fast and has multiple options to move data to and from ES cluster.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump

2. Copy data from S3 to DDB, this step pretty much depends on the fields you have in your DDB table. You can configure the pipeline in AWS as per the info below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html